# Force image div container to stretch inside custom image box layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I develop custom image box html control which contains image area along with small image thumbnails collection located at the bottom, top, left or right from the main image.
The problem is the main image div container doesnt stretch to fill remain area in main frame div.

Here is my code

```css
.wvIBoxFrameDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
 }

.wvIBoxMainImageDiv {
    background: green;
}

.wvIBoxThumbContainerDiv{
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wvIBoxThumbImagesContainerDiv{
    background: blue; 
    display: inline-block; 
}

.wvIBoxThumbNavigationDiv{
    background: purple;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.wvIBoxThumbImageDiv{
    background: orange;  
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wvIBoxFrameDiv">
    <div class="wvIBoxMainImageDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="wvIBoxThumbContainerDiv">
        <div class="wvIBoxThumbNavigationDiv"></div>
        <div class="wvIBoxThumbImagesContainerDiv">
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wvIBoxThumbNavigationDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I need thumbnails div container (with black background) placed in the bottom of main (red) frame div, while main image div (with green background) should stretch to fill remain area.

What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `height` and `width` as `100%` to `.wvIBoxMainImageDiv`

```css
.wvIBoxFrameDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
 }

.wvIBoxMainImageDiv {
    background: green;
    height:100%; /*this here*/
    width:100%; /*and here*/
}

.wvIBoxThumbContainerDiv{
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wvIBoxThumbImagesContainerDiv{
    background: blue; 
    display: inline-block; 
}

.wvIBoxThumbNavigationDiv{
    background: purple;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.wvIBoxThumbImageDiv{
    background: orange;  
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wvIBoxFrameDiv">
    <div class="wvIBoxMainImageDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="wvIBoxThumbContainerDiv">
        <div class="wvIBoxThumbNavigationDiv"></div>
        <div class="wvIBoxThumbImagesContainerDiv">
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
            <div class="wvIBoxThumbImageDiv"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wvIBoxThumbNavigationDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to have one strange behaviour: image container with 100% height fills all space (300px) within outside frame div. So bottom thumbnail div moves out of outer frame. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can either reduce it by some `%` or try giving `display:inline-block` to the children of main `div`

Comment: **[How about just reducing the %](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dxsoh5q7/9/)**? Is that allowed?

Comment: well, height of the bottom thumb region is determined by heights of all children (stretches to biggest one). So I need image container to fill the rest space

Comment: @Sergey In that case you can make use of `display` as `table` and `table-row` and `table-cell` but then the height again matters here as shown in this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dxsoh5q7/10/)** and in this case you might need to take help of `javascript` or `jquery` as you said your thumbnail height varies based on largest thumbnail.. Why don't you keep thumbnails a common height?

Comment: hmmm... I can't see image it your demo. It seems that I'll have to use js to set sizes manually. Well, I wonder why such a natural task has no acceptable solution. I just want bottom container to have natural height (determined by its' content) while upper image container fills the rest of global space. It is pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flex, (using auto-prefixer):

```
<div class="fullGallery">
  <div class="mainImage">
  </div>
  <div class="bottomImages">
    <div class="navigationButton">
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <div class="oneImage"></div>
      <div class="oneImage"></div>
      <div class="oneImage"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigationButton">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.fullGallery {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.mainImage {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bottomImages {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}
.navigationButton {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
.imageContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.oneImage {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 26%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYrdQJ

I like it more

Comment: Well, actually it works perfect with flex before I founded that flex is not supported on some mobile devices. So now I try to redevelop a dozens of html and css from flex to something else

Comment: Well... I mean, http://caniuse.com/#search=flex With auto-prefixer It should be ok, it's supported by almost 95% of the world, but If you are focused in a kind of public then... good luck, it Is a pain this supports... :(

Comment: Yes, I saw caniuse results, but my iphone safari and nokia chrome looks exacly like they never heard abour flex. It is pretty strange, but it seems that I just have no other choice.